# Has anyone used Redshift to source an Excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, ssas

Is it possible to use Amazon Redshift as the data source for an Excel pivot table?  Googling this question didn't yield any obvious answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes I have.

However since the other answers were written, rather than use generic PostGres drivers, you should use customised Redshift Drivers provided by Amazon.

The answers you are looking for are here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-connection.html

Answer (score 2):

You can consume Amazon Redshift databases with the [PostGRESQL ODBC drivers](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/).

1. Download and install driver.
2. Set up a DSN on the box pointed to your Redshift server with your AWS credentials (you can find the ODBC connection string in the settings area of your cluster.)
3. Use that connection in Excel or any other product that can connect to ODBC connections.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert Excel to CSV and upload it to S3. Once files are uploaded to S3 you can run copy command to copy data from S3 to Redshift cluster. You can run copy command via PostGRESQL JDBC connector or available tools like SqlWorkbench.

Comment: This is the opposite of the question that was asked.